# NPM keep running for hastebin server

Tags: node.js, apache, ssh, npm, server

I have hastebin installed at /var/www/paste/hastebin/

To start the NPM server I must navigate to hastebin location and then input:

```
npm start
```

This gets the server running with this

```
# npm start

> haste@0.1.0 start /var/www/paste/hastebin/
> node server.js

info: compressed application.js into application.min.js
info: loading static document name=about, path=./about.md
info: listening on 0.0.0.0:7777
debug: loaded static document success=true
```

If i disconnect from my ssh session i can no long get to example:7777

What can I do to keep this running after disconnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the session open I suggest installing `screen`

run `screen` to open up a terminal session that is "Behind the Scenes" - then once you run the `npm start` command simply hit CTRL+AD to "disconnect" from the screen session.

Now the service should be running in the background.

Hope this helps!